# how to load new view method?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have 2 views and 1 viewController :

In the first view I have added another view:

```
[self.view addSubView:self.secondView];
```

In Second View when i Press Back then i have remove the second view for back to the first View

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
```

but in my first view there is the `UITableView` I have to use `[UITableView reloadData];` method of `UITableView` but I don't know which method is called when secondView is removed.

My main objective is to call some method when I remove the second view and call any method which will reload the data.

I have tried many times but to call the method and delegates of the view but nothing happen, `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` no method is catch for the second time.. please tell me...

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `viewWill...` methods to run, you should use one of the view controller or modal view display methods rather than manually adding the subview. For example, using a `UINavigationController` is probably the best approach for what you're describing. Alternately, you can use the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method to present a modal view.

See the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information on handling transitions between views.

Comment: in presentModelViewController can i access the all the methods when i intiate the presentModelViewController Activity .. ??

Comment: I don't know what this means.